# Is there a way to set variables equal to eachother inside of an if statement?

Tags: perl

I'm working on a homework assignment that gives me the task to take four user-inputted numbers and compares them to output the largest and the smallest. I can't use loops so I'm using if/else/elsif statements but I keep getting an error. I've got this so far and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[Shebang]

```
my $small;
my $big;

print "\nEnter first number: ";
chomp (my $one = <>);

print "\nEnter second number: ";
chomp (my $two = <>);

print "\nEnter third number: ";
chomp (my $three = <>);

print "\nEnter fourth number: ";
chomp (my $four = <>);

if ($one >= $two) {
    $one = $big;
    $two = $small;
}
else {
    $one = $small;
    $two = $big;
}

if ($three >= $big) {
    $three = $big;
}
elsif ($three <= $small) {
    $three = $small;
}

if ($four >= $big) {
    $four = $big;
}
elsif ($four <= $small) {
    $four = $small;
}

print "LRG: $big\n";
print "SML: $small\n";
```

Ideally, you type in four numbers and it outputs the largest and smallest. Instead, I get 
"Use of uninitialized value $big in numeric ge (>=) at [filename].pl line 29, <> line 4." at line 29 and 36. 
I also get 
"Use of initialized value $small in concatenation (.) or string line 44, <> line 4."

Comment: All your assignments are backwards.  e.g. you say `$one = $big` where you mean `$big = $one`

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I guess I didn't know it had to be a specific way to define variables like this.

Answer (score 2):

Perl works the same way as pretty much every other programming language. In an assignment statement, the value on the right-hand side of the operator is assigned to the variable on the left-hand side of the operator. So, in a statement like:

```
$one = $big;
```

You assign the value of `$big` to the variable `$one`. As has already been pointed out in a comment, this is the wrong way round and you really wanted:

```
$big = $one;
```

There are a couple of simpler approaches, you can take. Firstly, you could sort the list of numbers and then take the first and last elements from the list:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } ($one, $two, $three, $four);
my ($small, $big) = @sorted[0, $#sorted];
```

Or you can use the `min()` and `max()` functions from the module [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util).

```
use List::Util qw[min max];

my $small = min($one, $two, $three, $four);
my $big   = max($one, $two, $three, $four);
```

Comment: List::MoreUtils's `minmax` is faster if you want both the min and the max

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah, but I prefer to use core modules when writing answers for obvious beginners.